# Student-t Fisher Information wrt log(sigma)?

Tags: expected-value, t-distribution, integral, fisher-information

I am having some issues finding any information on how to compute the fisher information of a student-t distribution when the standard deviation is parameterized as $log(\sigma)$ rather than $\sigma$.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271898/expected-fishers-information-matrix-for-students-t-distribution) post has some good information on how to go about calculating the fisher information matrix wrt $\sigma$.

The derivative of the log likelihood wrt $\mu$ comes out to comes out as $\frac{(v + 1) (y - μ)^2}{(y - μ)^2 + v σ^2}$.

The derivative of the log likelihood wrt $log(\sigma)$ comes out as $\frac{(v + 1) (y - μ)}{(y - μ)^2 + v σ^2}$.

The three integrals needing computation are:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(v + 1) (y - μ)^2}{(y - μ)^2 + v σ^2} \right)^2 f(y, \mu, \sigma, v) dy $$

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(v + 1) (y - μ)}{(y - μ)^2 + v σ^2} \right)^2 f(y, \mu, \sigma, v) dy $$

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \frac{(v + 1) (y - μ)^2}{(y - μ)^2 + v σ^2} \right)\left( \frac{(v + 1) (y - μ)}{(y - μ) + v σ^2} \right) f(y, \mu, \sigma, v) dy $$

Where $f(y, \mu, \sigma, v)$ is the likelihood of the Student-t. The first one has been done before as per [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271898/expected-fishers-information-matrix-for-students-t-distribution) post and comes to:

$$ \frac{v+1}{(v+3)\sigma^2} $$

If anyone could point me to some resources to calculate the second two, I would be much appreciative!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that deriving the reparametrized version is not that difficult if you have the original solution. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Reparametrization) section describes the process, basically just multiplying by second derivative of the reparam.

The final answer for this comes out to:

$$ \frac{v}{2 \left(v+3\right)\sigma^2} $$